# Correct way to make a "back/cancel" button in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I wanna know what the correct way of a back button is.

These are the options i found.

```
<a href="{{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}">Cancel</a>
```

And

```
<button onclick="history.go(-1)">Cancel</button>
```

I'm curious if there is any other/better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Cancel</button>
```

This will use the window.history.back() function, which goes back to the previous page in the browser's history.

Quite similar to your second option but it is easy to read and understand and best way according to me.